# Aggregate sum of a field when another row with the same ID is selected in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id int
);

CREATE TABLE attributes
(
  user_id int,
  k char(100),
  v char(100)
);

insert into users values (1);
insert into users values (2);
insert into users values (3);

insert into attributes values (1, 'k1', 'v1');
insert into attributes values (1, 'k2', 2);
insert into attributes values (2, 'k1', 'v1');
insert into attributes values (2, 'k2', 7);
insert into attributes values (3, 'k1', 'v2');
insert into attributes values (3, 'k2', 11);
```

What I want is

- For every distinct `v1` in the attributes table, sum the value of another row under the same `user_id` and has `k=k2`

So I want result like

```
 v1 9
 v2 11
```

Current SQL:

```
SELECT v, '?' as total 
FROM users 
JOIN attributes ON users.id = attributes.user_id 
WHERE k = 'k1' 
GROUP BY v
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36920/3/0

Comment: It seems strange to me that you're using the third column both to contain strings and integers you'd like to sum. Can't you just have a column for the string ('v1') and a separate column for the integer? I feel like that would simplify the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "sum the value of another row"? Which row should be summed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's exactly what you need. I would completely agree with aardvarkk though, that the wiser choice in the end will likely be to just simplify your schema. Anyways..

```
SELECT a1.v, SUM(a2.v) FROM users u
INNER JOIN attributes a1 ON a1.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN attributes a2 ON a2.user_id = a1.user_id AND a2.k = 'k2'
WHERE a1.k = 'k1'
GROUP BY a1.v
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table sumv
(
vnmbr nchar(2),
v int
)
declare @nmbr nvarchar
set @nmbr = 1
while @nmbr < 3
begin
insert into sumv (vnmbr,v)
select 'v'+@nmbr,v from attributes where [user_id] in (select [user_id] from attributes
where v = 'v'+@nmbr) and v not like 'v%'
set @nmbr = @nmbr + 1
end
select vnmbr,sum(v) as [sumv] from sumv group by vnmbr
```